# While deleting an element from an object, its deleting from the parent in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some data in state, in a method i am trying to remove something from that state data, so i have assigned that state data to a variable and deleting some data from that variable, but its deleting from that state object which i dont want, why that's happening and how to stop that.

```
this.state.Columns = [{columnName: "ABC", columnType: "BCD", moduleName: "OIU"},
                        {columnName: "BCD", columnType: "KIO", moduleName: "NHJ"},
                            {columnName: "BHY", columnType: "NJH", moduleName: "MKO"}]

let {columnsForModule} = this.state;                        
let columnForModule = this.state.Columns;

let columnsByModule = Lodash.groupBy(columnForModule, "moduleName");

moduleItems= ["MKO","NHJ","OIU"];


for(var i = 0 ; i < moduleItems.length ; i++){
      if(columnsByModule[moduleItems[i]]){

        let columnModule = columnsByModule[moduleItems[i]];
        for(var m=0;m<columnModule.length;m++){
          var key = "moduleName";
          console.log(columnModule[m]);
          columnModule[m] = delete columnModule[m][key];
          columnsForModule.push(columnModule[m]);
        }
      }
    }
```

after all iteration i want,

```
this.state.Columns = [{columnName: "ABC", columnType: "BCD", moduleName: "OIU"},{columnName: "BCD", columnType: "KIO", moduleName: "NHJ"},{columnName: "BHY", columnType: "NJH", moduleName: "MKO"}]
```

this.state.columnsForModule = [{columnName: "ABC", columnType: "BCD"},
   {columnName: "BCD", columnType: "KIO"},{columnName: "BHY", columnType: "NJH"}]

Here my question is while deleting from `columnModule[m][Key]` its deleting from the root object also which is `this.state.Columns`, i don't want this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clone the object before making any change, since javascript object work by reference. You can use [`spread operator syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to make a shallow copy. However since you are trying to modify the nested data, you need to do deep clone.

```
let columnsForModule = [...this.state.columnsForModule];                        
let columnForModule = this.state.Columns.map(column => ({...column})); // deep copy
```

Comment: now also its deleting from the root one "this.state.Columns"

Comment: Thank you Shubham, it works now.
As i was deleting from reference, it was deleting from parent also as javascript object work by reference. Is this the logic?

But in other places i have directly removed from reference,its not impacting.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes it works by reference, and will affect at places where you don't make a copy before removing or modifying objects. spread operator makes a one level deep copy so even while writing `[...this.state.Columns]` , the individual column objects key/value still point to the same reference as in original and hence you needed to do deep clone